# WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

Tags: c#, winforms

Приложение написано с использованием WinForms. При установке свойства:

```
WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

форма разворачивается во весь экран и перекрывает панель Пуск. Это не удобно. Каким образом можно развернуть форму до панели Пуск? (При это Свойство FormBorderStyle строго установлено в None). Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данный код должен развернуть вашу форму на весь экран, при этом не скрывая таскбар.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        Left = Top = 0;
        Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width;
        Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вариант рабочий. Спасибо.